# How to pass a already implemented Component inside the Copilot Step in react-native-copilot

Tags: react-native

I am trying to built a guided tour for my app using react native copilot

```
https://github.com/okgrow/react-native-copilot
```

and i cannot figure out how to use a already built component inside the its CopilotSteps as mentioned in the tutorial.

This is the my code so far and it gives me the following error

```
  <CopilotStep
        text="This is a hello world example!"
        order={1}
        name="hello"
      >
        {({ copilot }) => (
          <Card snow to={`${basePath}/account`} {...copilot}>
            <Row inline justify="center" fluid>
              <Block inline justify="center">
                <FIcon name="shield" size={25} />
              </Block>
              <Block justify="center">
                <P compact>Account and Security</P>
                <P compact small helper>
                  Edit Your Account Information
                </P>
              </Block>
              <Block inline justify="center">
                <FIcon name="chevron-right" size={25} />
              </Block>
            </Row>
          </Card>
        )}
      </CopilotStep>
```

error =>

```
D:\My Work\Company Projects\Ongoing\ZappyFoods\Mobile App\zappyfood_app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:63 Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

what should i do to get this code run proerly

Comment: Are your imports correct? Are your exports correct in the components you are importing? Which of those components are custom built?

Comment: please check here https://github.com/mohebifar/react-native-copilot#custom-components-as-steps

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the component "walkthroughable", so for example if my original component was a simple `TouchableOpacity` button.

```
 <TouchableOpacity
   onPress={this.callFunction}
 >
   <Icon name="photo" type="FontAwesome" />
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Then to make it work with copilot first import walkthroughable.

```
import {
  copilot,
  walkthroughable,
  CopilotStep
} from "@okgrow/react-native-copilot";
```

Then call the `walkthroughable` function passing our `TouchableOpacity` component.

`const WalkthroughableTouchableOpacity = walkthroughable(TouchableOpacity);`

Finally add the copilot step and use the new Walkthroughable component in place where you would've used `TouchableOpacity`.

```
<CopilotStep
  text="Hey! This is the first step of the tour!"
  order={1}
  name="openApp"
>
  <WalkthroughableTouchableOpacity
    onPress={this.callFunction}
  >
     <Icon name="photo" type="FontAwesome" />
  </WalkthroughableTouchableOpacity>
</CopilotStep>
```

So the entire file could look like

```
import {
  copilot,
  walkthroughable,
  CopilotStep
} from "@okgrow/react-native-copilot";
import { Icon } from "native-base";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

const WalkthroughableTouchableOpacity = walkthroughable(TouchableOpacity);

class Example extends Component {
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    this.props.copilotEvents.on("stepChange", () => {});
    this.props.start();
  };

  callFunction = () => {
    console.log("Button Pressed.");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <CopilotStep
        text="Hey! This is the first step of the tour!"
        order={1}
        name="openApp"
      >
        <WalkthroughableTouchableOpacity onPress={this.callFunction}>
          <Icon name="photo" type="FontAwesome" />
        </WalkthroughableTouchableOpacity>
      </CopilotStep>
    );
  }
}

export default copilot({
  animated: true,
  overlay: "svg"
})(Example);
```